# Could a male klepton work?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, centaur

Would it be possible to have an all-male species, that reproduce by mating with females of other species, but with the female's genes being removed during fertilisation, so that the result is another member of the all-male species.

Comment: What's different between your question and this one https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/142340/30492 ?

Comment: That question asks about humanoids which reproduce without ova

Comment: This is the premise of the book Mothership
(Ever-Expanding Universe #1)
by Martin Leicht, Isla Neal

Comment: [Edible frogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edible_frog), *Pelophylax* kl. *esculentus*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

Hydatidaform moles are complications of pregnancy.  Instead of a fetus, a bunch of weird tissue grows.  The most common are androgenetic moles: DNA is only from the father, arising from 1 (sometimes 2) sperm.

[Causative Mutations and Mechanism of Androgenetic Hydatidiform Moles](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30388401)

> Androgenetic complete hydatidiform moles are human pregnancies with no
>   embryos and affect 1 in every 1,400 pregnancies. They have mostly
>   androgenetic monospermic genomes with all the chromosomes originating
>   from a haploid sperm and no maternal chromosomes...
>
> It is believed that after
>   fertilization between a haploid sperm and an oocyte that has lost its
>   nuclear DNA (for simplicity referred hereafter as empty oocyte), the
>   paternal genome endoduplicates to reconstitute diploidy. Then, because
>   the paternal and maternal genomes have different roles in cellular
>   proliferation and embryonic differentiation, the androgenetic genome
>   that results from such a zygote leads to the molar phenotype.

The existence of androgenetic moles mean that an ova from which maternal DNA has been kicked out can be taken over by a sperm (sometimes two!) and give rise to viable cells, if not a viable organism.

If you take it one step further and give the sperm the ability to organize cytoplasm and embryogenesis in the way an egg can, instead of growing up to be a hydatidiform mole it could grow up to be a baby.  It would be homozygous at every gene (and female) if created by a single sperm, although could be heterozygous and possibly male if created by 2 sperm.

This is just in humans.  If it can get this close in humans, having males of a fictional species sometimes hijack the apparatus of reproduction for their own fitness benefit makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

Not in the way you’re thinking.

If two creatures can ‘breed true’ and produce a fertile child then they are not, in fact, different species. That means your ‘all Male species’ is just a part of the greater species which may have many wildly varying morphs to give the illusion of different species (ants being one such example and Portuguese men-o-war another, though you may wish to opt for less colonial examples)

But that’s boring. Let’s go for something a little more exotic.

Your ‘all Male’ species is actually a hermaphroditic race of cuckoos. They self-fertilise, then use what must be a very comprehensive and flexible (in terms of utility, get your minds out of the gutter) ovipositor to deliver the fertilised package into the womb of a different species. When there this package will exude the right hormones to ‘trick’ the host into thinking that they’re pregnant, giving the cuckoo foetus all the nutrients and care it needs. Birth may get tricky: not only must your embryo be ready at the right time by the ‘mothers’ biological clock it must also be the right shape and able to deal with the rigours of birth without either getting crushed or causing massive trauma to the mother.

This is an indicator of the problem with this approach: such parasitism tends to occur in *extremely* specific hosts. Your cuckoos need to exactly mimic any number of things at a biological level for this to have a remote chance of working, which leaves them limited to a very small number of potential hosts (likely just one target species). Even the difference between very closely related species might be enough to prevent a successful ‘impregnation’, and though you could feasibly handwave this for an alien biosphere I wouldn’t try to say they can get humans pregnant (for example) unless they’re also capable of genetically manipulating their reproductive systems to ensure compatibility.

If they’re advanced enough to do that then I’m not sure why they aren’t just building artificial wombs.

Comment: But if they are hermaphrodites, they aren't all-male

Comment: If that’s a distinction you absolutely insist upon then I refer you to my first paragraph: If these are truly Male but also able to breed true with some other female then *they are the same species*

Comment: Unless you take some of the answers from the other linked question and apply those, but even then you’ve just got a self-fertilising species with motile gametes, which is just as hermaphroditic. Unless of course multiple sexual partners are required, which makes the ‘female’ a glorified incubator.

Comment: They don't really breed with the females in a genetic way, they just replace the egg's genes with their own, and make the egg grow into an embryo

Comment: [Kleptons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klepton) actually exist.